# Simple solutions for integrating MySQL with C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, database, integration

What solutions are there for making a simple connection to a MySQL database in C++?
I find MySQL Connector from dev.mysql.com hard to integrate.

Anticipated thanks!

Comment: What do you define as a "simple" connection?

Comment: simple: connect -> query -> close, and my bad, I also should have mention simple before the "solutions". Seems like others agree that integrating mySQL connector is a pain http://r3dux.org/2010/11/how-to-use-mysql-connectorc-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-windows/ ...I mean, why didn't the MySQL install manual didn't mention boost library was required?

Comment: [mysql++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/)?

Comment: mysql++ is not windows supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty simple to communicate with MySQL from C/C++ application

you need to include mysql.h header file

three basic APIs to connect and execute query

mysql_connect()

mysql_query()

mysql_close()

Link with mysql library (libMysql)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the ODBC path, with a support library.

Some year ago I used [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/) to interface SqlServer and found it efficient. Now I've tried to interface MySql, without any problem so far:

```
#include <otlv4.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int otl_x_sql_main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    otl_connect db; // connect object
    otl_connect::otl_initialize(); // initialize ODBC environment
    try {
        db.rlogon("DRIVER=mysql;DB=...;UID=...;PWD=..."); // connect to ODBC

        // parametrized SELECT
        otl_stream i(50, "SELECT product_id,model FROM product WHERE product_id >= :f<int> AND product_id < :ff<int>", db);

        int product_id;
        char model[100];

        i << 1000 << 2000; // assigning product_id range

        // SELECT automatically executes when all input variables are assigned
        while (!i.eof()) {
            i >> product_id >> model;
            cout << "product_id=" << product_id << ", model=" << model << endl;
        }
    }
    catch(otl_exception& p) {       // intercept OTL exceptions
        cerr << p.msg << endl;      // print out error message
        cerr << p.stm_text << endl; // print out SQL that caused the error
        cerr << p.sqlstate << endl; // print out SQLSTATE message
        cerr << p.var_info << endl; // print out the variable that caused the error
    }

    return 0;
}
```