# C++ app MySQL odbc database connection error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'otl_tmpl_exception<>

Tags: c++, mysql, database, odbc, connection-string

I am currently debugging a containerized C++ application, it seems like it's throwing exception and complaining about the database connection, error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'otl_tmpl_exception<odbc::otl_exc, odbc::otl_conn, odbc::otl_cur>'
Aborted
```

The code in main() is below:

```
int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
        auto otl_connect = std::make_unique<odbc::otl_connect>("Driver={/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc8a.so};server=xxx.x.x.x;port=xxxx;database=xxxx;user=xxx;password=xxx");
        std::stringstream query;
        query << "SELECT x FROM xxx.xxxs;";
        odbc::otl_stream the_stream(1000, query.str().c_str(), *otl_connect);

        std::string
        int val;
        while(!the_stream.eof())
        {
            the_stream >> xxx >> val;
            std::cout << xxx << " " << val << "\n";
        }
        the_stream.close();
}
```

I'm totally new to C++, can someone explain what the codes in main() is doing and how to fix the exception error message, I've been working on this for a whole afternoon, exhausted....help!!!!

Comment: You might be missing a step, e.g. initialising the ODBC environment with `otl_connect::otl_initialize();` Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465594/simple-solutions-for-integrating-mysql-with-c/11466100#11466100 It's also worth enclosing your database operation in a `try...catch` block to catch the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the Oracle, ODBC and DB2-CLI Template Library but I had a go using it with a MySql database on my Ubuntu Linux.

This is how I was able to run a simple query. I think the code below is fairly self-explanatory.

As you'll see, it's quite different from your code. The driver is `mysql`. You have to substitute `...` with the real database name, user name and password of your database. You also have to initialise the ODBC environment first and connect to your database using `rlogon()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#define OTL_ODBC // Compile OTL 4.0/ODBC
#define OTL_ODBC_UNIX
#include "otlv4.h"

int main()
{
    otl_connect db; // connect object
    otl_connect::otl_initialize(); // initialize ODBC environment
    try {
        db.rlogon("DRIVER=mysql;DB=...;UID=...;PWD=..."); // connect to ODBC

        otl_stream os(50, "SELECT id FROM task", db);

        int id;
        // SELECT automatically executes when all input variables are assigned
        while (!os.eof())
        {
            os >> id;
            std::cout << "id=" << id << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch(otl_exception& p) {       // intercept OTL exceptions
        std::cerr << p.msg << std::endl;      // print out error message
        std::cerr << p.stm_text << std::endl; // print out SQL that caused the error
        std::cerr << p.sqlstate << std::endl; // print out SQLSTATE message
        std::cerr << p.var_info << std::endl; // print out the variable that caused the error
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Make sure that you have a variable for each field you want to read from the query result. It seems that you can't extract values into `std::string` variables; you have to use char arrays (e.g. `char name[20]`) instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using Windows and wanted to run the query against a dockerised database, will that be the same?

Comment: @Cecilia Are you able to connect to the dockerised database from a Windows terminal? What URI do you use? You will have to update the connection string in the code above to able to connect. You might find these sources useful: http://otl.sourceforge.net/otl3_examples.htm and https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I have read it, because I have very limited knowleadge about odbc and docker, I don't think I fully understand them, I raised another question to cover this issue, would be great if you take a look, thank you.