# 'Could not SQLConnect' error when connecting dockerised model and dockerised database

Tags: c++, mysql, docker, docker-compose, odbc

I'm trying to connecting a dockerised c++ application with a dockerised database so that I can get it running and get some outputs, the configuration can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717701/c-app-mysql-odbc-database-connection-error-terminate-called-after-throwing-an?noredirect=1#comment110910866_62717701)

when I try to run the model (which inside the application container) against the dockerised database:

```
>docker run --net xxxxx-network  -it xxxxxrun:localbase
root@xxxxxxxx:/run# isql xxx.x.x.x user=root
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

I'm new to odbc and docker, can someone gave me some hint? Many thanks.

Comment: how you are running SQL in docker is to compose file or command and please share command ? if possible please look your docker container status running or stop by `docker ps`

Comment: run mysql docker using : docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:5.7

Comment: You must have got the docker images from Docker Hub. What are the image names? I'm particularly interested in image you used for the application container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your running each docker container separately.
In this case in order for your C++ application container to be able to connect to
the Mysql container they will need to be on same network.

1. Create Docker network `docker network create mysql-network`
2. Run C++ application container like so: `docker run -it --network mysql-network xxxxxrun:localbase` (*xxxxxrun* should be name of image and *localbase* should be image tag that you want to run)
3. Run Mysql database with command similar to `docker run --network mysql-network -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:5.7`

In this situation the two containers should be able to communicate freely with each other across the network.